# Can’t install any software from old Debian

Tags: debian, aptitude

Looks like I can't install any software since I run Old Debian Lenny. Is it possible somehow change installation sources for system?

[image]

UPD

I have updated my sources, but still can't install software:

```
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contribi
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main contrib non-fre
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lenny is EOL and no longer supported since 2012.

From [DebianLenny](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLenny) on the Debian wiki:

> Lenny is the code name for a former DebianStable distribution. It was
>   released on Feb 15th, 2009 as Debian GNU/Linux 5.0. It was superseded
>   by Debian/Squeeze on Feb 06th 2011. It has been archived and no longer
>   receives security updates.
>
> 2012-02-06 : End of security updates / End of life. (post). 2012-03-10
>   : Updated (5.0.10) (press release).

That said, if you still need it:

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should be:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free     
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment any additional lines, mainly that one pointing to the installation media.

Updated question:

You need to do an `apt-get update` or `aptitude update` before installing any package.

Comment: Depending on when it appeared on Debian, this might also be needed `apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update` `apt-get -o  Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false install ...` etc.

Comment: never mind, this option is not referenced in lenny's /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz . Seems it appeared in squeeze (so would be needed after next dist-upgrade)